# how to add cell in excel above another cell via proc report

Tags: sas

```
ods listing close;
ods tagsets.excelxp file='Y:\fonts\CC_ACQ_fonts_v2_har.xls' style=sasweb
options(sheet_name="CC_ACQ_JUN12_V2");
proc report data=work.matrix_input nowd
 style(report)={font_face=times font_size=1 font_weight=bold bordercolor=black}
 style(header)={font_face="Times New Roman" font_size=8pt  font_face=times    cellwidth=1in background=gray foreground=black font_weight=bold bordercolor=black  }
 style(column)={font_face="Times New Roman" font_size=8pt 
         just=center cellheight=15in font_face=times};
 column CELL offer_description pop product;
 run;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
ods listing;
```

know first column in excel is CELL know above CELL(Column name) i want to write BY:CELL (in another cell) 
and above offer_description pop product (3 Columns) above i want to write TOTAL Consilodate Mail) with green color as background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  Basically you use the ACROSS variables to get your second header, and then you have to put in a nonprinting dummy column in order to get things to behave (you cannot have entirely ACROSS variables).  You can put in the colors with style statements.  Your code will look cleaner if you use PROC TEMPLATE to define the styles so you can use style inheritance to not rewrite your styles over and over again.

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
total='Total Consolidated';
namedummy='By Name';
dummy=' ';
run;

ods listing close;
ods tagsets.excelxp file='c:\temp\test.xml' style=sasweb
options(sheet_name="CC_ACQ_JUN12_V2");
proc report data=class nowd
 style(report)={font_face=times font_size=1 font_weight=bold bordercolor=black}
 style(header)={font_face="Times New Roman" font_size=8pt  font_face=times    cellwidth=1in background=gray foreground=black font_weight=bold bordercolor=black  }
 style(column)={font_face="Times New Roman" font_size=8pt 
         just=center cellheight=15in font_face=times};
 column dummy namedummy,name total,(age height weight);
define total/' ' across style={font_face="Times New Roman" font_size=8pt  font_face=times    cellwidth=1in background=green foreground=black font_weight=bold bordercolor=black };
 define namedummy/' ' across;
 define dummy/noprint;
 run;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
ods listing;
```